# MSTest stops debugging tests outside test project in 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest

I have no idea how this started so I'm guessing there's a setting somewhere that I've been unable to find.  I have a test that calls a method but when I run debug, it simply will NOT step into that dll.  At all.  Period.  Throws an exception just fine, but it's kind of worthless when I can't step into see what's actually going on.

When another team member picks it up, he's able to debug the exact method I was attempting to target.  Yes, same breakpoints, yes, same code (I checked in, he got it, ran just fine)

What the hell?

update : checked the test project for stupid entires, deleted the debug/release folders for fun, I've went though and dumped the project completely and got it back out of tfs.  I've nuked the appdata/local/ms/vs/10.0 folder and the /appdata/roaming/ms/vs/10.0 folder.  Deleted the local test results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to investigate your project references.  Is the DLL possibly GAC'd?  Take a close look at the *.csproj file.

The fact that it can be debugged no problem on someone else's machine indicates to me that you're having an environment issue.  Some sort of multiple library reference issue.

Another possibility:  Visual Studio (and all its embedded tools) can have many strange caching behaviors.  You might want to clear out extraneous MSTest-related temporary cache files/dirs.

Comment: I wish it was csproj ... vb :-( Know what you mean though, checked it, looks fine (all project refs) (stackoverflow REALLY NEEDS to take line breaks in comments) ---- right, what's why I think there's a setting somewhere I hit/checked/did without really knowing. ----- I carpet bombed the test result directory, did the manual nuke of the debug folder ... any other places I should look? (Not running ANY 3rd party tools)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.  You can't do one of those things and it works.  I had to do them all prior to opening up vstudio again.  It'll blow your settings away just as a heads up.

Kill the AppData/Local/Microsoft/visualstudio/10.0 folder

Kill the AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/visualstudio/10.0 folder

Kill your entire project ... all of it.

Get latest (force)

And it works again.